# How to restrict the number of lines to show using jquery or css?

Tags: javascript, web-part, jquery, jquery-ui

i have created simple Custom webpart. 
It looks like

[image]

in that web part, Description display multiple line .
i have used html P tag to display  **Description** value

```
<p>​Loream Ipsum​Loream Ipsum​Loream Ipsum​Loream Ipsum ​Loream Ipsum​Loream Ipsum​Loream Ipsum​Loream Ipsum​​​​</p>
```

currently i m trying to hide lines **more than two** using jquery in all resolution.
is that possible ? please suggest something ?

Comment: Use CSS to set the ``height:2em`` of the P tag and use ``overflow:hidden``

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
​Loream Ipsum​Loream Ipsum
​<p id="link">
    Loream Ipsum​Loream Ipsum
</p> 
​Loream Ipsum​Loream Ipsum​Loream Ipsum​Loream Ipsum​​​​</p>
```

associate 'id' to the 'p' tag and hide the line whichever you want using jquery.

```
 $("#link").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a JQuery plugin http://keith-wood.name/more.html you could use. It allows you to truncate text at a given length.

```
$(selector).more({length: 60});
```

There are lots of settings that this plugin has.

```
  $(selector).more({     
              length: 100, // Truncation length     
              leeway: 5, // Overrun allowed without truncation     
              wordBreak: false, // True to break between words, false to break anywhere     
              ignoreTags: ['br', 'hr', 'img'], // Non-terminated tags to ignore     
              toggle: true, // True to toggle, false to display and exit     
              ellipsisText: '...', // Display text for ellipsis     
              moreText: 'Show more', // Display text for more link     
              lessText: 'Show less', // Display text for less link     
              andNext: '', // Selector for any following tags to include in the collapse     
              onChange: null // Callback function when expanded/collapsed 
});
```